# What's the point of using composition when the composed class is only used at a single place?

Tags: python, design-patterns

I see some code design like this

```
class my_class:
  def __init__(self, arg1, arg2, arg3)
    self.data = data(arg1, arg2, arg2)
    # initialize some other attributes

# the only place data class is used is in my_class
class data:
  def __init__(self, arg1, arg2, arg3)
    self.arg1 = arg1
    self.arg2 = arg2
    self.arg3 = arg3
```

I don't see the point of doing that, when you can just do

```
class my_class:
  def __init__(self, arg1, arg2, arg3)
    self.arg1 = arg1
    self.arg2 = arg2
    self.arg3 = arg3
    # initialize some other attributes
```

which gets rid of the seemingly unnecessary layer.

Is there some advantage of design standard that motivates the former design?

Comment: In the example you posted the additional layer is indeed not necessary. There can be real-world situations though where you want to completely hide the API of the inner class and expose its functionality through the API of the outer class. If I'm not mistaken, it's called a facade in the "design patterns" lingo.

Comment: While it might only be used in one place now, this allows for future use in other places.

Answer (score 0):

Composition frequently is NOT the most idiomatic way to design your class, especially in the sort of example you suggest, because the use case may not only be obscure at the time of writing, it may not even exist yet.

Three arguments why you should prefer it anyway:

First, testing and refactoring your classes NOW is easier if they comprise smaller modular blocks.

Second, a future modification to your code is less likely to be awful and soul destroying if your code is structured in neatly separated chunks that operate as integral wholes that come together in different ways.

Third, separating responsibilities is a good general principle to espouse. If your class does two things: maintain state, and change state, separating those two responsibilities into two separate objects that do one thing each will tend to be easier to write, test, refactor, extend, and, frankly, just reason about.

Closer to your example, if you're writing a class solely to hold data, you might consider using `collections.namedtuple` or `data classes.dataclass`. This affords you some lightweight containers with nicer ways to access fields, and builtin repr and str methods. You can then pass these modular containers of data to a composed class that then does something with them.